# Acess opened window from different pages

Tags: javascript, dom

Is it possible to store a window opened using `window.open()` and access it from an other page?

Here's how I open the window:

```
win = window.open("jmap.php?id="+id);
```

As the parent page is navigated (other pages of the web site are accessed), I'd like to call the previously opened window's function:

```
win.zoomToPlainte(id)
```

How do I save the `win` variable across pages?

Comment: in non-IE you can use `window.opener`

Answer (score 1):

**As long as both windows are in the same domain**, this is possible.

You'd need to save a reference to the opened window object like you're doing with:

```
var win = window.open("jmap.php?id="+id);
```

Window objects have a `document` property which allows you access its DOM like so:

```
win.document.getElementById(...);
```

Or you can call global functions/variables through using a window object:

```
win.someGlobalFunction();
```

To travel back from the child window to the window object that opened it, use the `window.opener` property, which returns a window object:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById(...);
window.opener.someGlobalFunction();
```

Comment: Note that `window.opener` is non-standard and not supported in f.ex IE

Comment: @David the `window.opener` property is non-standard but is supported in all browsers, including IE.